# Angular and Leaflet error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: angular, leaflet

I want to use @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet

my angular version is 8.1.2

```
ERROR in node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/dist/leaflet/layers/base/leaflet-baselayers.directive.d.ts:22:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

22     set baseLayers(v: {
           ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/dist/leaflet/layers/base/leaflet-baselayers.directive.d.ts:25:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

25     get baseLayers(): {
           ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/dist/leaflet/layers/control/leaflet-control-layers.directive.d.ts:21:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

21     set layersControlConfig(v: LeafletControlLayersConfig);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/dist/leaflet/layers/control/leaflet-control-layers.directive.d.ts:22:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

22     get layersControlConfig(): LeafletControlLayersConfig;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/dist/leaflet/layers/leaflet-layers.directive.d.ts:24:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

24     set layers(v: Layer[]);
           ~~~~~~
node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/dist/leaflet/layers/leaflet-layers.directive.d.ts:25:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

25     get layers(): Layer[];
           ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/geojson/index.d.ts:69:13 - error TS2456: Type alias 'Geometry' circularly references itself.

69 export type Geometry = Point | MultiPoint | LineString | MultiLineString | Polygon | MultiPolygon | GeometryCollection;
```

How can I fix this error

Answer (score 0):

Your problems seems to be that version of TypeScript used by your current version of `@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet` is incompatible with the version used by angular 8.1

Make sure you are using an older version of `@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet`. Looking at [their git repo](https://github.com/bluehalo/ngx-leaflet/), the earliest release is 8.1.0 (which btw has a pair of angular v10).

You might want to try this version 8.1.0, or maybe an earlier commit, from before that tag where it might have been compatible with angular 8.1;